# Solve for $x$ in $(3sf)$, where $\cos(x) - \tan(x) = 3 $.

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The problem I am struggling with to solve is this. I have already tried to solve it however I end up with quadratic $\sin$ or $\tan$ whichever way you do it, which does not help.

Solve for $x$ $(3sf)$ where:

$\cos(x) - \tan(x) = 3 $

from $0$ to $2\pi$

Comment: The fact that a solution to three significant figures is being asked for implies some sort of approximate (numerical??) solution.

Comment: indeed, the answers are 1.87, 5.07

Comment: Hint: Put it into the form $\cos^2 x - \sin x - 3\cos x = 0$ and use Newton's method.

Comment: Tried to express the relation in terms of $\tan\frac x2$ using this(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae), but it resulted in a biquadratic equation

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=\cos(x)-\tan(x)-3$$
$$f'(x)=\sin(x)-\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}$$

Now apply [Newton method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_method), by

- $x_0=2$ (guess something not too far by looking at a graph of the function $f$)
- $x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

And $x_{25}=1.865810565186072908108$ which is a very good approximation.

If you start with $x_0=5$, you'll find the second solution.